# Flip View with a Table inside?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I am trying to figure out how to make a flip view that would have a table in it. Basically I want to have a table with information for that day. Then you can flip to the next day or previous day and a new table would load up.

I am not sure how to do this though in Xaml. I will eventually have a data source that will connect to this table and pull the right information up but first I need to figure out how to write the xaml to make the table inside a flip view.

I am not sure if I should be using "Grid" or "Grid Layout".

**Edit**

I tried both these controls but was not really sure how to get it to have a column format nor how to get it so the flip view thought that there was more than one table(so it would give the controls to get to the next table).

**Edit2**

This is what I am trying to achieve (more styled up later and x number of rows per section and no border lines)

[image]

Comment: [What Have You Tried?!](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the [`Grid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.aspx) class shows how to add rows, columns etc. You can use `Grid` to do a layout with other elements placed in a few rows/columns. To use more than a few or to bind a collection - various ItemsControl classes are better - `ListView` & `GridView` are probably most common on Windows 8.

Comment: Ya I am looking at GridView right now. I am looking at the examples and confused on how they work. For instance the second example("In this GridView the ItemTemplate is applied to the first item (a string), but not to the second item (a GridViewItem). See Remarks for more info.") I don't understand why it applies only to the string. I don't see what is telling it to only apply to stuff with strings.

Comment: Is there a better example btw(one with code that I can run??).

Comment: For `GridView`? I don't know what example you are looking at. There are standard project templates that create an app with a `GridView` when you create a project in Visual Studio.

Comment: Sorry thought you linked to the same link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview. I have added what I am trying to do. I am not trying to make tiles I am trying to make a table.

Comment: `GridView` does not seem to be what you need. In WPF `GridView` was a table control. In WinRT/XAML it is more of a magazine cover design control based on a layout grid. What you need is the actual `Grid` control and the link I provided in the answer has a sample that might help you.

Comment: Ok. I will try that control. Would the flipview be wrapping around the grid or what?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You would simply place the Grid inside of a FlipView (it automatically creates a FlipViewItem in the visual tree for each child item you add to the FlipView that is not a FlipViewItem).